# How to implement Custom online shipping method with shipping API?

Tags: magento2, module, api, shipping-methods, rest-api

I have created one shipping module.I need to integrate flash express API's in that. How to integrate the APIs?

Comment: You can integrate it same place where currently you put fix cost of charges.

Comment: How do I send an HTTP Shipping Request in Magento2 from a custom shipping module?

Comment: Can you please help? its urgent.

Comment: As I told you, you need to implemented those things where you can return the cost of the shipping. take the magento default shipping method reference so you get idea.

Comment: Yes..I have added all the fields like ID ,key ,signature where i have added the cost..But how to implement the API functions?I have refered the Fedex module..but it uses WSDL..

Comment: You need to call the CURL code to call API and get response.

Comment: I a still getting trouble in implementing shipping Api

Comment: Can anyone one help?

Comment: I am using CURL and I have done it.

Comment: That really great.